# Ошибка при отправке сообщений по SMTP в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos, smtp

Вылезает ошибка при отправке сообщений в Ларавел.

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.yandex.ru :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.yandex.ru:465 (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

Пол дня провозился с поиском решений. Нашел по косвенным запросам, а не по самой ошибке. Ниже решение.

Решение проблемы оказалось достаточно простым - в случае с CentOS демон апача работает под именем httpd.
Проверяем возможность отправлять письма с помощью ПХП:

```
getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
getsebool httpd_can_network_connect
```

Если обе команды отвечают "off", то пишем:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

[Оригинал ответа](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=392630)